# if statement without an else or with an else?

Tags: r, if-statement

I am having some trouble interpreting a conditional here. Which one of these approaches would be better if I wanted this condition evaluated? Some code was shared with me that used this approach:

```
## Option 1
k1=2

a = "k1 is less than or equal 1"
if(k1 > 1) {
  a = "k1 is greater than 1"
}
print(a)
```

But my instinct would be do something like this:

```
## Option 2
if(k1 > 1) {
  a = "k1 is greater than 1"
} else {a = "k1 is less than or equal 1"}
print(a)
```

Is there any danger to using Option 1? Basically what I am asking here is what is the best practice and is either option more rigorous?

Comment: Both are fine. You'll find that `ifelse` gets used a lot more than `if` in R because it's vectorized. It drops attributes, though, which can cause issues if you're working with more complicated data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much danger in using option1 , option2 is better as it allows other people to understand the code faster/easier since it is more visible to read.Also, option1 sometimes give error on complicated codes.
But both options are fine in this case.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any danger to using option 1, as it works just as fine as option 2. The else statement just gives the ability to run a piece of code only if k1 is less than or equal to 1.

In a few cases, option 2 isn't so necessary especially if you only care about the condition being true. For example,

```
 if(today's date == birthday){

    System.out.println("Happy Birthday!");

} // no need for an else statement unless you want print out "today is not your b-day"
```